# How to select a column which has the maximum average among other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I have a table like

[image]

I want to find the column which has the minimum average value among column V1, V2, V3, in this case it is V1, what should I do in SQL?

Comment: I'm guessing you've been given down votes because you haven't shown your code or indication that you've attempted or researched anything.  Please post your code and indicate the places you don't understand or are given you trouble.

Comment: Do you wants V1 as the result? Or Average from V1 which is lowest?

Answer (score 0):

If you wants the lowest average value among all three columns, use this following script-

```
SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN AVG(v1) < AVG(v2) AND AVG(v1) < AVG(v3) THEN AVG(v1)
    WHEN AVG(v2) < AVG(v1) AND AVG(v2) < AVG(v3) THEN AVG(v2)
    ELSE AVG(v3)
END
FROM Your_Table
```

But if you wants the Column Name as output that contains the lowest average, you can use this following script-

```
SELECT   
CASE 
    WHEN AVG(v1) < AVG(v2) AND AVG(v1) < AVG(v3) THEN 'V1'
    WHEN AVG(v2) < AVG(v1) AND AVG(v2) < AVG(v3) THEN 'V2'
    ELSE 'V3'
END
FROM Your_Table
```

Comment: Extreme case, but let's say the average of V1 and V2 are equal, your answer would default to V3.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Opps!! not considered :( if there are possibilities of having same value from different columns, need to add more case in the script.